# How do I fix indentation/alignment in my pull request in Bitbucket?

Tags: javascript, bitbucket, sublimetext3, indentation, atlassian-sourcetree

I have written a small piece of `JavaScript` code (not allowed to share code). The code is aligned perfectly in text editor (`Sublime`) but in the pull request it is distorted. I tried to solve this but failed.

I tried to save each line but the result in pull request in still same. In `SourceTree` the indentation is correct before I push the code to the repository but after the push is successful the alignment dies.

Please forgive if this is a stupid question to ask to the developer community.

Sample code

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var validate = $("#formId").validate(
                   {
                       debug : true,
                       rules : {
                            Name : {
                                required : true
                            }
                       },
                       messages : {
                            Name: {
                                required : "Name is required"
                            }
                       },
                       onfocusout : false,
                       invalildHandler : function (form, validator)
                       {
                           var errors = validator.numberofInvalids();
                           if(errors)
                           {
                               validator.errorList[0].element.focus();
                           }
                        }
                    });
})
```

So this is how it is actually supposed to be (above code) but in the `pull request` it comes something like this

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var validate = $("#formId").validate(
                               {
                                   debug : true,
                                   rules : {
                                        Name : {
                                            required : true
                                   }
                               },
                                   messages : {
                                        Name : {
                                            required : "Name is required"
                                   }
                               },
                       onfocusout : false,
                       invalildHandler : function (form, validator)
                          {
                                   var errors = validator.numberofInvalids();
                                   if(errors)
                                   {
                                      validator.errorList[0].element.focus();
                                   }
                           }
                              });
})
```

Comment: Can you reproduce this issue with sample code that is not company sensitive and post the results/screenshots here?

Comment: @koelkastfilosoof sure. My bad. I should have done it in the first place.

Comment: Sounds like you have a mix of tabs and spaces and the width of a tab character is different.

Comment: You could set up [prettier](https://github.com/prettier/prettier) before commiting so the code has a standard format for everyone. Then use prettier again when you check out so the code is formatted how you like it.

Comment: That code is missing a `)` at the end.

Comment: @koelkastfilosoof please see if the sample code helps you to help me.

Comment: @ChrisG thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if it'd figure out the problem, but hope you'd make a try anyway.

1. Download the *conflicted* target `.js` file from **Bitbucket**. (It doesn't matter whether it's a `js` file or not.) It's easy to make a file download if you open it as a `raw` status.
2. Replace your *local* original file with that one. It means you're going to get rid of **confliction** from your local side.
3. Make a commit to remote **Bitbucket** repo by `git push -u origin [your_branch]`. If your branch is not the **master** one, make a **PR**(pull request) and update your *local* branches syncing with *remote* ones.
4. Now you can recover your own **indentation/alignment** style on your *favorite* editor as you wish! (local edit)
5. Finally, make a commit to **Bitbucket** again.

> To make a long story short, you can *apply* your own indentation after **Git** conflicts would get fixed.

Thanks.